# Is it possible to create a function that integrates the include directive? Java - JSP

Tags: java, jsp, include, directive

I'm want to build a function that makes something like:

```
void MyIncludeCompile(String TheFile) {
  "%><%@include file="+TheFile+"%><%";
}
```

I want to obtain an alternative to include directive building my own method or function.

Something like:

```
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(request, response, TheFile, out, false);
```

But, it's applicable to something:

```
void MyIncludeRun(String TheFile) {
  %><jsp:include page="+TheFile+"/><%";
}
```

In other words in translation time instead of run time.
As you can see:
The **include action** in run time have an equivalent using pure java code.

Is there an alternative to **include directive**?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't want to use include directive explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is no. You can implement your own include tag, for example `<my:include file="theFile"/>` and put your own logic into tag handler class, but it cannot be executed in translation time. In translation time, the JSP is converted into regular java file - into a sublass of `Servlet` to be more precise. Only the directives (and declarations) can make any changes to the servlet class (scriptlets and expressions put code into the service method, tags are handled at runtime). I don't know the implementation details of `JspRuntimeLibrary`, but since the include method's signature contains request and response objects, I think that it includes resources at runtime as well.